# Flutter iOS App: SocketException: OS Error: Bad file descriptor, errno = 9

Tags: ios, flutter, http, sockets, multipartform-data

Multiple Flutter iOS users of my app have received the following error in their application while sending a multipart request for uploading images:

```
SocketException: OS Error: Bad file descriptor, errno = 9, address = <back-end server domain>, port = 64362
```

The code to send the request

```
var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
request.files.add(
await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
 "images",
 imagePath,
 filename: imageName,
 ),
);
request.headers.addAll({
  "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
});
var response = await request.send();
var response2 = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
```

Comment: There is currently an open issue about this: https://github.com/dart-lang/http/issues/197